# FMX TContext3D How to change line width when drawing in TContext3D (using DrawLines function)

Tags: c++, 3d, drawing, firemonkey

I'm using Embarcadero Berlin Builder C++ FireMonkey. 
FMX TContext3D How can I change a line width when drawing in TContext3D (using DrawLines function) and how can I change points size when using DrawPoints.

For example:

```
Mesh->OnRender = WireframeRender; //Here I set an event
...
void __fastcall TVizualer::WireframeRender(TObject *Sender, TContext3D *Context)
{
    TMesh* M = static_cast<TMesh*>(Sender);
    TVertexBuffer* V;
    TIndexBuffer* I;

    V = M->Data->VertexBuffer;
    I = M->Data->IndexBuffer;

    Context->DrawLines(V, I, TMaterialSource::ValidMaterial(EdgeMaterial),1);
//Here I'm drawing a wireframe. It works, but I need to draw lines thicker
Context->DrawPoints(V, I, TMaterialSource::ValidMaterial(EdgeMaterial),1);
//Here I'm drawing points. It works, but I need to make points bigger

}
```

Comment: I added an example of code. Could you please look at it once again ?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge in those tags, I just tried to help you making your question more answerable